# Compressing a netCDF file with the pynco package

Tags: python-3.x, nco, pynco

I'm interested in compressing a NetCDF file in python using the `pynco` package. From the command line, I would usually use:

```
nccopy -d 3 input_file.nc output_file.nc
```

In python, I have tried the following:

```
from nco import Nco
Nco.nccopy(input='input_file.nc', output='output_file.nc', options=['-d 1'])
```

This produces an attribute error `'Nco' has no attribute 'nccopy'`. Is `nccopy` supported within `pynco`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nccopy` is a netCDF command, not an NCO command.  However, `ncks` can do nearly everything `nccopy` does, and a whole lot else. To compress as in your example, try

```
Nco.ncks(input='input_file.nc', output='output_file.nc', options=['-7 -L 1'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to list an alternative to `pynco`, you can also do this within python using the `cdo` package:

```
from cdo import *
cdo = Cdo()
cdo.copy(input='input.nc',output='output.nc',options='-f nc4 -z zip_7')
```

You can choose the compression level from light (`zip_1`) all the way up to most compressed (`zip_9`), I usually find that going above level 4 or 5 there is not much gain (i.e. additional size saving very minor) for a lot of pain (command takes a lot longer!).  I think the `-f nc4` to ensure netCDF4 output is perhaps not needed if the input is netCDF4 standard, but it doesn't hurt to put it anyway.

You can install cdo with

```
pip3 install cdo
```